# A relation involving solutions of a quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

Consider the following quadratic equation:
$$x^2 - (a + d) x + (a d - bc) = 0,$$
where $a, b, c, d \geq 0,$ and let $x_1 > 0, x_2 < 0$ be the solutions. I read in a book that since
$$x^2 - (a + d) x + (a d - bc) = \Big[x - \frac{a + d}{2}\Big]^2 - \Big[ \frac{(a - d)^2}{4} + ad - bc \Big],$$
and $\frac{a + d}{2}$ is nonnegative, then $x_1 > |x_2|$. Can someone explain me why is it true?

Comment: $x_1\gt |x_2|$ does not always hold. If $(a,b,c,d)=(0,1,1,0)$, then $x_1\le |x_2|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Since we know the roots of the given quadratic (and that it is monic), we can also write it as
$$(x - x_1) (x - x_2) .$$

> **Additional hint** On the other hand, expanding this expression and comparing like terms in $x$ in our two different ways of writing the polynomial gives $$a + d = x_1 + x_2 .$$